# Magento 2: How to hidden tab fieldset in form ui component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, forms, tabs

i want hide this field. everyone can help me plz!
[image]

[image]

Comment: custom tab or magento core tab ??

Comment: i want hidden custom tab

Comment: you can delete tab also

Comment: No, i just want hidden it.

Comment: because i have conditions

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the method isComponentVisible()

```
namespace Custom\Custom\Ui\Component\Form;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\ComponentVisibilityInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

/**
 * Class Fieldset
 * @package Custom\Custom\Ui\Component\Form
 */
class CustomFieldset extends Fieldset implements ComponentVisibilityInterface
{
    /**
     * CustomFieldset constructor.
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;

        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isComponentVisible(): bool
    {
        $visible = //add logic
        return (bool)$visible;
    }
}
```

And in your xml you just need to include this class in the fieldset

```
<fieldset name="custom" sortOrder="30" class="Custom\Custom\Ui\Component\Form\CustomFieldset">
```

Comment: This is only working in Tab Fieldset not in Normal fieldset. Do you have any idea to show hide Normal Fieldset by using php class?

Comment: Working perfect!

Answer (score 2):

In **ui_component**

It's just a demo

```
<fieldset name="design">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
```

in your code what you need to hide just put like

```
<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

Comment: Yes, i have hidden but just contents still tab not hidden :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to hide the fieldset based on condition.

**Step 1:** Override prepare method of your fieldset like below.

> Your Form.xml

```
<fieldset name="menu_items" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\CustomFieldset">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label>Menu Items</label>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </settings>
    <fieldset name="assign_applicants">
        <settings>
            <label>Menu Items</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        </settings>

        <field name="name" sortOrder="30" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">menu</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

> Prepare method of your component fieldset class CustomFieldset.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\ComponentVisibilityInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

/**
 * Class Fieldset
 * @package VendorName\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form
 */
class CustomFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    /**
     * @var \VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * RuleInformationFieldset constructor.
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     * @param \VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        \VendorName\ModuleName\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * hide or show fieldset based on module enabled or disabled.
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        $visiable = false;
        $config = $this->getData('config');

        if( $this->helper->isModuleEnable() ) {
            $visiable = true;
        }

        $config['visible'] = $visiable;
        $this->setData('config', $config);
        
        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** You need to disable the whole fieldset then add the following code in your Data provider class.

```
/**
 * Get meta function.
 * return mixed
 */
public function getMeta()
{
    $meta = parent::getMeta();

    if($this->helper->isModuleEnable()) {

        $meta['menu_items']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 1;
    } else{
        $meta['menu_items']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 0;

    }
    return $meta;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**In Tab File You Can Set Tab Visibility Like This :-**

```
public function canShowTab()
{
    return false;

}
public function isHidden()
{
    return true;

}
```

Comment: i can't call function that

Comment: tab is create using ui ??

Comment: Can you give me example? i an understand :(

Comment: I don't know how to call function that for my tab!

Comment: find in block any tab folder ???

Comment: im create custom tab under order view so thats tab file path like/vendor/module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Tab/myfile.php

Comment: So how to use in form ui

Comment: please attach code..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94046/discussion-between-rk-rathod-and-newbie).